# What is the correct way to apply word embeddings to new data?

Tags: natural-language, word-embeddings

Consider the words "banana" and "split". Assume that a pre-trained word embedding (say, word2vec GoogleNews) has the vectors like so:

`banana_vec = array([[1.56, -2.46, 6.13, ... , -2.81]])`

`split_vec = array([[3.56, 9.45, -2.43, ... , 5.32]])`

Now consider a completely new data set consisting of documents (sentences). Assume that one of the documents is the sentence "banana split".

How does one represent that sentence with the pre-trained word embeddings?

Things I've considered include:

**Sum word embedding elements for each word**

So this would give something like

`bananana split = array([[v1, v2]])`

where `v1` is the sum of elements in `banana_vec`, and `v2` is the same for `split_vec`.

**L2 norm of word embedding elements for each word**

So this would be the same, but the L2 norm instead of the sum.

**Sum word embedding elements across words**

So this would be:

`banana split = array([[v1, v2, v3, ... , v100]])`

where `v1 = 1.56 + 3.56`

**L2 norm of embedding elements across words**

Same as above except `v1 = sqrt(1.56^2 + 3.56^)`.

Or is it something completely different?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pre-trained word embeddings that have been loaded, each word will have a vector of the same length, $n$.

```
doc_vectors = []
for doc in documents:
    doc = tokenize(doc)
    feature_vector = zeros_array(n)
    for word in document:
        vec = vector (embedding) for the word
        feature_vector += vec
    feature_vec = feature_vec / len(doc)
    doc_vectors.append(feature_vector)
```

**So for the example in the question:**

`vec("banana") = array([[1.56, -2.46, 6.13, ... , -2.81]])`

`vec("split") = array([[3.56, 9.45, -2.43, ... , 5.32]])`

1. `feature_vec("banana split") = vec(banana) + (split) = array([[5.12, 6.99, ..., 2.51]])`
2. `feature_vec("banana split") = feature_vec("banana split") / length`

And that is how feature vectors are achieved for documents embeddings, which was one of the suggestions in the question.